# Reportportal results grouped by test environment

Tags: reportportal

On our project we try to collect all tests results into reportportal. 
For unit tests we applied java agent for junit and api tests are executed over gauge framework. Since our project has several tests environments before the application is shipped to production i would like to display the results aggregated per environment. Like local, development, staging, e2e, production and group the results accordingly. Is there such feature available?

Answer (score 1):

Since reportportal v5.1 supports attributes that can be passed over api
`rp.attributes = key:value; value;`
Hence passing environment:foo. 
On these attributes filters can be applied.